# Scheduled task running on demand but not by itself with stored Windows credentials

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, task-scheduler

I have a scheduled task that is supposed to run an **application located in a server**.

The access to the server is only allowed to a specific user, so in order to be able to execute such application, or even browse the contents of the specified application's path, you need to login using user credentials. **These credentials have been added to the Windows Credentials Manager as Windows Credentials**.

Having credentials already stored, I can easily access the folder where the application is located and I can even execute it there myself with no trouble.

The problem happens when the application is supposed to be executed by the scheduled task. When the triggers run the task, **it can't find the specified path and ends with the exit code 0x80070002**.

I find this problematic because **if I go to the task scheduler and manually run the task**, which runs the application in the server, **it works out fine**, it runs the application and exits with code 0x0, this without changing anything to the credentials configuration. This also fixes itself when I visit the application's path in the server.

The scheduled task's triggers are supposed to run the application hourly, however once it has failed it keeps failing every hour, but if it ran fine, it will keep running fine every next hour.

The server's path is defined by an IP address, not by domain.

**This usually happens only after turning on the computer for the first time of the day**, if it has started working it will work even if I restart the computer.

Other scheduled task's settings:

- Run only when the user is logged on.
- Trigger: Hourly.
- Action: Start a program.
- Condition: Start as long as its connected to any network.
- Allow task to be run on demand.
- Stop the task if it runs longer than 5 minutes
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop.

What could possibly be causing this behaviour? Why does it not work when the task is ran by the scheduler?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but are you allowed to tick the box for "run as highest privileges"? Also, the user running, if not a domain admin, may need to be set in the GPO under the "run as batch" user list. One more thing, does any interaction happen on a network drive? Sometimes when booting back up, a computer doesnt connect to mapped drives so you should only use full UNC paths for example `\\computer3\sharedDrive\test`. Also, make the sure the sccript itself does not reference a mapped drive and uses UNC paths

Comment: I forgot to mention but yes the `Run with the highest privileges` is ticked. The drive is not mapped, the path is as follows: `\\#.#.#.#\folder\app`. I'm not sure about that specific aspect of this user's GPO, I will  have to check that tomorrow.

Comment: Is the user specified in `When running the task, use the following user account:` the same user that has permission to run the application?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Yes.

Comment: Is the task running an executable that's stored on a different computer? What's in the box where you specify what program to run?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes that's what it does. The program's path. \\#.#.#.#\path\app.exe

Comment: Is the app a command line/console program or a GUI? Consider having the task run a batch file that in turn runs the app. Then you could do some simple logging in the batch file to see if the task can indeed access that path (e.g. Ping the IP, map a drive to the remote share, etc.)

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator It is a console application, it runs in the background.

Comment: Also, try starting the task after a short delay.

Comment: Wait a second...If you have to logon as the user in order for the task to run, why did you have to store the user's credentials in Credentials Manager? That makes no sense.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The task is supposed to run with the active user. The login I mention is only needed for the network shared folder, which does require authentication

Comment: @user1676874 I wonder if that's the problem. Try doing a `net use` command to map a drive to the target share before running the target command. You'll need to do this in a batch file.